# Is there any way to encode Non Numeric values in a dataframe column

Tags: python, dataframe, random-forest, sklearn-pandas, encoder

I have a dataframe which includes both numeric and non numeric values (It includes some special characters like -, space etc). I want to encode that Non Numeric value to run corr(). Non numeric Column name eg: 'Department', 'Location', etc. I used Label Encoder(). But it shows a TypeError;

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

I used this code :

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

X_train['Department'] = le.fit_transform(X_train['Department'])

Answer (score 0):

If the data is not ordinal, I wouldn't use LabelEncoder with corr(), as that will yield false insight.

`pd.getdummies(X_train['Department'])` has been adequate for using `pd.DataFrame.corr()` for me. It will create as many columns as there are classifications, and mark 1 for each row where the classification matches the column label, otherwise 0.

The other issue is possibly mixed datatypes in 'Department', which can be fixed with `df['Department'] = df['Department'].astype('str')`. It's probably most efficient to do this before your train-test split.